# RAML API Designer File Save Location

Tags: raml

I have just started to play around with RAML. I ran [API designer](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-designer) locally using `grunt server` and used that to design a simple api doc in RAML.

Does that `raml` file get saved in the local file system? I coudn't find the location where that file get saved in the local file system. I need that file since I've to commit it GIT repository.

Comment: The RAML file is stored in the Browsers' LocalStorage, not the filesystem per se.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your files with the export function. there's no other way to do that.

Comment: Can you please explain how to use that export function?

Answer (score 0):

Import/export works with zip files.

[Api designer menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17How.png)

Comment: What is the API Designer you are using? I'm running https://github.com/mulesoft/api-designe locally and it don't have the export button. It has Import feature only.

Answer (score 0):

The export button doesn't show with the default localStorageFileSystem. You need a different file system that allows exporting, e.g. [RAML API Designer File Save Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129196/raml-api-designer-file-save-location) or https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-raml-store

Answer (score 0):

For the record, at the time this question was asked, there was an issue with the locally run API designer (see [api - designer issue #248 here](https://github.com/mulesoft/api-designer/issues/248)). Since then, the issue was solved and it works fine now.